# Why can I not view my blog entries in cms_plugin blog?

Tags: python, django, templates, plugins, django-cms

Why can't I see the blog entries I have made using cmsplugin blog for Django-cms?

I have [django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/) setup on a development server (localhost). I installed [cmsplugin](https://github.com/fivethreeo/cmsplugin-blog) using the instructions documented [here](http://cmsplugin-blog.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

When I go to "http://localhost:8000/admin/" Cmsplugin_Blog appears under site administration. From the entries page I am presented with an overview of the entries I have made. Editing an individual entry, I can add a plugin (text) and add text for that entry. I then make sure that the the particular entry is published.

Going to my blog page (CMS->Pages) I then choose cmsplugin_blog and add the latest entries plugin (I can not see any other relevant plugins). Finally I choose advanced settings -> Application -> Blog Apphook (and save). When I preview the blog page I can only see the dates of the last entries and the headings of the entries.

I'm not sure if it's something I did wrong within my setup so I included the process I went through to set up cmsplugin.

I edited INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'cms',
    'cms.plugins.text',
    'cms.plugins.picture',
    'cms.plugins.link',
    'cms.plugins.file',
    'cms.plugins.flash',
    'cms.plugins.googlemap',
    'cms.plugins.teaser',
    'cms.plugins.video',
    'cms.plugins.twitter',
    'cms.plugins.snippet',
    'cms.plugins.inherit',
    'cmsplugin_contact',
    'cmsplugin_gallery',
    'mptt',
    'menus',
    'south',
    'sekizai',
    'cmsplugin_blog',
    'djangocms_utils',
    'simple_translation',
    'tagging',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

And also added:

```
JQUERY_JS = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js'
JQUERY_UI_JS = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js'
JQUERY_UI_CSS ='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'


JQUERY_UI = '/path/to/jquery/'
JQUERY_JS = '%sjs/jquery-1.4.4.min.js' % JQUERY_UI
JQUERY_UI_JS = '%sjs/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js' % JQUERY_UI
JQUERY_UI_CSS = '%scss/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css' % JQUERY_UI

CMSPLUGIN_BLOG_PLACEHOLDERS = ('first', 'second', 'third')

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('template_1.html', 'Template One'),
    ('template_2.html', 'Template Two'),
    ('footer.html','Template Footer'),
    ('sidebar.html','Template Sidebar'),
    ('cmsplugin_blog/cmsplugin_blog_base.html','cmsplugin_blog'),

)
```

I the created a template  "cmsplugin_blog/cmsplugin_blog_base.html":

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
    {% block left-col %}{% endblock %}
    {% block right-col %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

And then ran:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

After having the problem described in my question I created a new template **view_detail.html**:

```
{% extends "cmsplugin_blog/cmsplugin_blog_base.html" %}

{% load placeholder_tags cmsplugin_blog_tags simple_translation_tags %}


{% block left-col %}
{{ block.super }}

<h1>{% with object|get_preferred_translation_from_request:request as title %}{{ title }}{% endwith %}</h1>

<p class="date"><span>{{ object.pub_date|date:"d F Y" }}</span></p>

{% with object.placeholders|choose_placeholder:"content" as content %}
    {% render_placeholder content %}
{% endwith %}

{% endblock %}

{% block right-col %}

{% render_author_links %}

{% render_month_links %}

{% render_tag_links %}

{% endblock %}
```

However, when I attempt to use this template in the cms I am not able to add any plugins to the page and I still have the original problem. This is a full copy of my [settings.py](http://pastebin.com/wrypPGn4) for reference.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem correctly, but when you use an AppHook (like in the case of cmsplugin_blog), you won't be able to place any plugins because the apps urls, views and templates take precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. When I change 'content' in the following line in cmsplugin_blog/templates/cmsplugin_blog/entry_detail.html then the 'first' placeholder is rendered as blog content:

```
{% with object.placeholders|choose_placeholder:"content" as content %}
```

new line:

```
{% with object.placeholders|choose_placeholder:"first" as content %}
```

I do not have enough experience with django to understand what causes this, hope someone can provide more clues.